# VBA equivalent to Excel's mod function

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

Is there a vba equivalent to excel's `mod` function?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You want the [mod operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/se0w9esz(VS.80).aspx).

```
The expression a Mod b is equivalent to the following formula:

a - (b * (a \ b))
```

**Edited to add:**

There are some special cases you may have to consider, because Excel is using floating point math (and returns a `float`), which the VBA function returns an integer. Because of this, using `mod` with floating-point numbers may require extra attention:

- Excel's results may not correspond exactly with what you would predict; this is covered briefly [here (see topmost answer)](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-excel/problem-with-the-mod-function-in-excel/b1d6be13-7180-e011-9b4b-68b599b31bf5) and at great length [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/78113).
- As @André points out in the comments, negative numbers may round in the opposite direction from what you expect. The `Fix()` function he suggests is explained [here (MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/int-fix-functions).

Comment: You'd better change `(a \ b)` for `Fix(a / b)`. Otherwise, you may have problems with decimal arguments. Try your formula with `a = 1.75` and `b = 1` and you'll see my point.

Comment: The formula suggested is wrong and will always produce 0 as answer

Comment: @PSVSupporter I think you're confusing the `  \ ` operator with `/`. They're different.

Comment: \ and mod are both 32 bit only.  / and int seem to work on double.

Answer (score 60):

In vba the function is MOD.
e.g

```
 5 MOD 2
```

Here is a useful [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa164528%28office.10%29.aspx).

Comment: +1 the VBA language reference page for `Mod` is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264708%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Comment: The mod operator is not equivalent because it cannot return floating precision, unlike the excel function.

Comment: Be aware that the Excel MOD function calculates differently than the VBA Mod operator when negative numbers are used.  I just discovered this with simple integers.  I expected to see more explanation of this issue on this page.
In VBA  `11 Mod -5 = 1`  where as Excel's formula  `MOD(11,-5) = -4`
In my case I decided to use the XLMod() function shown on this page instead of the Mod VBA operator.

Answer (score 10):

My way to replicate Excel's `MOD(a,b)` in VBA is to use `XLMod(a,b)` in VBA where you include the function:

```
Function XLMod(a, b)
    ' This replicates the Excel MOD function
    XLMod = a - b * Int(a / b)
End Function
```

in your VBA Module

Answer (score 9):

Be very careful with the Excel MOD(a,b) function and the VBA a Mod b operator.
Excel returns a floating point result and VBA an integer.

In Excel =Mod(90.123,90) returns 0.123000000000005 instead of 0.123
In VBA 90.123 Mod 90 returns 0

They are certainly not equivalent!

Equivalent are:
In Excel: =Round(Mod(90.123,90),3) returning 0.123 and
In VBA: ((90.123 * 1000) Mod 90000)/1000 returning also 0.123

Comment: There are many warnings about floating point results. +1 for providing an example.

Answer (score 3):

The [`Mod` operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/se0w9esz.aspx), is roughly equivalent to the [`MOD` function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/mod-function-HP010342698.aspx):

`number Mod divisor` is roughly equivalent to `MOD(number, divisor)`.

Answer (score 2):

```
Function Remainder(Dividend As Variant, Divisor As Variant) As Variant
    Remainder = Dividend - Divisor * Int(Dividend / Divisor)
End Function
```

This function always works and is the exact copy of the Excel function.

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you include some explanation along with it to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked.

Answer (score 0):

But if you just want to tell the difference between an odd iteration and an even iteration, this works just fine:

```
If i Mod 2 > 0 then 'this is an odd 
   'Do Something
Else 'it is even
   'Do Something Else
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

### I've found this to be the most reliable if excel's mod function is also giving incorrect results:

Originally even
XLMod = (a - (b * Int(a / b))) was giving me incorrect results so..

```
Function XLMod(a, b As Long)
' This replicates the Excel MOD function - the VBA mod function returns an integer

Dim templong As Long

  templong = (b * Int(a / b))
  XLMod = (a - templong)
End Function
```

Comment: Var  type has to be declared for each variable. Parameter `a` will be a variant in this case.
Double might also be preferable.

Answer (score -1):

The top answer is actually wrong.

The suggested equation:
`a - (b * (a \ b))`

Will solve to: `a - a`

Which is of course 0 in all cases.

The correct equation is:

`a - (b * INT(a \ b))`

Or, if the number (a) can be negative, use this:

`a - (b * FIX(a \ b))`

Comment: \ operator
 is not the same as / operator

\

The result is the integer quotient of expression1 divided by expression2, which discards any remainder and retains only the integer portion. This is known as truncation.

The / Operator (Visual Basic) returns the full quotient, which retains the remainder in the fractional portion.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0e16fywh.aspx

Comment: -1 As explained by Cheeky Charlie this answer is misleading, based on an incorrect assumption; if you aren't convinced, try entering _Msgbox 3 - (2 * (3 \ 2))_ in the Immediate window in the VBA editor, which returns 1 as expected from the modulo function instead of 0 as posited by this poster.