# Assign and retrieve excel cellValues in excel by using macros

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to VB programming. Can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here:

```
Dim somevariable as Integer

somevariable = WorksheetFunction.QUOTIENT(Range(Sheet1!A1), Range(Sheet1!B1))
```

Thanks

Comment: What error are you getting when running your code?

Comment: Run-time error '424'" Object Required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Completely new answer as of given details. You are working with `VBA` so you can call **WorksheetFunctions** like

```
Dim someVariable
someVariable = WorksheetFunction.Quotient(Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, "A").Value, Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, "B").Value)
Debug.Print someVariable
```

There is a quite good list of supported functions available on [MSDN WorksheetFunction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn301180%28v=office.15%29.aspx). Please choose your current Excel version on the linked page.

Furthermore I found another very important site concerning your problem that states that **not all WorksheetFunctions are supported as Application**. (see [support.microsoft.com](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/107564/en-GB))

So I searched for workarounds and found a quite simple one on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4378047/vba-equivalent-to-excels-mod-function). But on the other hand - you really could make use of the VBA builtIn operator **[MOD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/se0w9esz.aspx)**

```
' created some variables, as I made some attempts on creating a good example
Dim value1
value1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, "A").Value

Dim value2
value2 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, "B").Value

someVariable = value1 Mod value2
Debug.Print someVariable

' of course you may use a single line statement too
someVariable = Worksheets("Tabelle1").Cells(1, "A").Value Mod Worksheets("Tabelle1").Cells(1, "B").Value
```

I think there are some pretty good links to have a deeper look into.

Comment: OK, between some of the suggestions I got here and a little more trying I got this to work:  
  
    somevariable = WorksheetFunction.Quotient(Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, "A").Value, Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, "B").Value)   
  
but when I tried to do the same thing using Excel's MOD function I got a new error   
  
"Run time error 438: Object doesn't support this property or method".   
  
It's the exact same code except in one case I am using the Excel "QUOTIENT" function and in the second case I am using the MOD function. Any thoughts?

Comment: also - apologies for not formatting - I read the instructions.  I put 4 spaces in front of my code but it doesn't appear as indented, mono-spaced code.  and I ended several lines with 2 spaces to create a newline. that didn't seem to work either

Comment: I'll have a look into your new question. But first please verify that we are talking about `VB.net` and not `VBA`. Furthermore please add some more information eg. what **framework version** or what **office version** you are using.

Comment: Not being a developer (so not having a in-depth understanding of the difference between the two) I would say that I am talking about VBA. I am just trying to do a few things in macros within Excel. I am running MSOffice 2010 and 2013 (depending if I'm poking at this from work or at home)

Comment: so you are coding in a macro - it's vba. VB.Net would be within VisualStudio and coding against .net Framework. I'll recheck my answer and add some new code for your problems

Comment: completely rewrote my answer - now containing vba code!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
somevariable = WorksheetFunction.QUOTIENT(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(A1), Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(B1))
```

Comment: thank you all - Pilgerstorfer gave me what I was looking for but I learned a lot from everyone's answers.