# Excel error on function MOD

Tags: vba, excel

I want to input this formula in my excel file (VBA preferably). But from some reason I get an error when I put this function im my formula bar:

```
#NUM! - Number Error
```

My function is:

```
=98-mod(2000000000123456*100;97))
```

But When I enter just 10 digits, then it works. I need to work with 16 digits.
I am trying basically to validate number based on  ISO 7064 Mod 97,10 formula
Thanks in advance.

Thanks pepople, for your effort, but I've tried code that @Robyn wrote, and I get overflow error. Here is my code (I will write just Function section):
'Note: An entering paramters are: 3259300700853850 and 97

```
 Function DblMod(Dividend, Divisor)
' Declare two double precision variables
Dim D1 As Double
Dim D2 As Double
' Copy function arguments to local variables
D1 = Dividend
D2 = Divisor
DblMod = D1 Mod D2
End Function
```

Comment: But Excel can handle only ***15*** digits.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent I feel inclined to specify: you can [enter and use much larger numbers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x99xtshc.aspx). But Excel should not be used if a precision beyond the 15th digit is important: http://superuser.com/questions/373997/adding-more-than-15-digits-in-excel

Comment: I believe my solution will work for your situation.

Comment: Can you please say the correct answer for 3259300700853850 (Dividend)  and 97 (divisor)?

Comment: All the examples in bounty description have wrong results. `98-mod(3100400300327166;97)=50` **but** `98-mod(3100400300327166*100;97)=51`, you have correct answer from @RonRosenfeld, if it doesn't work - you have to describe in detail why.

Comment: @BrakNicku As you wrote, my UDF gives all the correct results (as per the current rendition in bounty description).  When Stefan commented that he was having a problem with the UDF, I asked about system separator issues, as that is one cause, but he never responded.  I will post a screen shot of his numbers and the results of my formula in my Answer.

Answer (score 4):

As has been written, Excel has a limitation of 15 digits precision.  So when you enter your formula above, your 16-digit number will be altered:

`2000000000123456` becomes `2000000000123460`

One way to do work around this limitation involves using VBA and also changing your formula.

Instead of writing  `16 digit number * 100`, enter the entire value as a string:

"200000000012345600"

eg:

```
=98-xMOD("200000000012345600";97)
```

Then use this UDF which makes use of the increased precision afforded by VBA's Decimal data type:

```
Option Explicit
Function xMOD(Num As Variant, Div As Long)
    Dim x As Variant, y As Variant

x = CDec(Num)
y = CDec(Div)

xMOD = x - Int(x / y) * y

End Function
```

If you will be entering your 16 digit number (**as a string**) in some cell, and always multiplying by 100, you can use the following formula:

```
=98-xMOD(C1&"00";97)
```

Or, you could just enter the 18 digit number, **as a string** into some cell and reference it in your formula, omitting the `&"00"` part.

Another option, if you can find it, would be an unsupported free add-in called `xNumbers`.  The latest version `6.0` still works with Excel 2016, although the integration with the ribbon is non-existent, so some of the configuration options cannot be used.

**EDIT** Since you wrote that you were unable to get this UDF to work in your system, I will post a screen shot showing that it does work in mine, and also that it agrees with the results you have posted in your bounty description.  (xIntMod from xNumbers also returns the same results)

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately it doesnt let me to run this function, "The formula you typed contains an error".

Comment: @Stefan0309 are you using the correct system separator signal for your Locale. Semicolon vs. Comma period

Comment: @Stefan0309 Have you checked your system separator that the one you are using is correct for your locale?  If that is correct, please copy and paste (do NOT type in) your exact formulas and data to which the formula refers or, preferably, upload a workbook that shows the problem and post a link here.

Comment: Smart solution, you could even slim down the function to just one line      i.e. 'xMOD = CDec(Num) - Int(CDec(Num) / CDec(Div)) * CDec(Div)'

Comment: @EEM Thanks.  One liner's are fun, but they can sometimes make the algorithm a bit more difficult to decipher.  I've never tested to see if there is any speed advantage of one way over the other.

Answer (score 0):

**For numbers with abs() less than or equal to 2,147,483,647**

This is a known issue per the Microsoft Support article [XL: MOD() Function Returns #NUM! Error Value](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/119083).

Note that this article is quite dated - so this might not be the true root cause in your instance.

The article suggests the following as a workaround:

> Instead of using this formula `=MOD(J13,K13)` use this formula: `=J13-(INT(J13/K13)*K13)`

Alternatively, [this article](http://excel.tips.net/T003302_Large_Numbers_in_the_MOD_Function.html) suggests a VBA equivalent:

```
Function DblMod(Dividend, Divisor)
    ' Declare two double precision variables
    Dim D1 As Double
    Dim D2 As Double

    ' Copy function arguments to local variables
    D1 = Dividend
    D2 = Divisor

    DblMod = D1 Mod D2
End Function
```

**For numbers with abs() greater than 2,147,483,647**

In this scenario, the VBA MOD function overflows with `Run Time Error '6': Overflow`. This is addressed in Microsoft Support article [PRB: "Overflow" with Integer Division and MOD Operator](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/205053). The article suggests the below solution in VBA, which I have tested works as expected with the OP's given numbers:

```
Sub Main()
    Call DblMod2(3259300700853850, 97) 
    ' returns 46, which matches the Big Integer Calculator at http://www.javascripter.net/math/calculators/100digitbigintcalculator.htm suggested by Ron
End Sub

Function DblMod2(Dividend, Divisor)

    Dim dblX As Double
    Dim dblY As Double
    dblX = Dividend               ' numerator
    dblY = Divisor                ' denominator

    ' round off the numerator and denominator (ensure number is .0)
    dblX = Int(dblX + 0.5)
    dblY = Int(dblY + 0.5)

    ' Emulate integer division with: Fix(dblX / dblY)
    ' Emulate modulo arithmetic with: dblX - (dblY * Fix(dblX / dblY))
    DblMod2 = dblX - (dblY * Fix(dblX / dblY))
    Debug.Print DblMod2
End Function
```

Comment: I've tried this vba code, but it returns  an overflow error. I'm not sure that is correct?

Comment: Neither of your solutions will work as the OP wants to deal with 16 digit numbers

Comment: I thought Excel could handle very long numbers - just with the caveat of imprecision - so I dug further. I'll update my suggested solution shortly.

Comment: Hi @Stefan0309, my suggested solution is updated above. This gives me the expected numbers (in Excel 2013).

Comment: But the number you are testing is `200,000,000,012,346,000` and the number in the OP's post was `200,000,000,012,345,600`

Comment: Also, I think, even using your `200,000,000,012,346,000 ` value, you are getting the wrong result.  Using your code in Excel 2016, I get `94` as the result.  Using my code, xNumbers, or an online [Big Integer Calculator](http://www.javascripter.net/math/calculators/100digitbigintcalculator.htm), I get `13` as a result.

Comment: For number `160580010074623000` it must be 7 and for example `160580010074613000` it must be also 7 control digit.

Comment: @Stefan0309  Those are not the correct results for the formula `MOD(160580010074623000,97)` ► `95`  and `MOD(160580010074613000,97)` ► 86

Answer (score 0):

There is an alternate for the MOD function [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4378047/vba-equivalent-to-excels-mod-function)

```
a - (b * (a / b))

=98-((2000000000123450*100)-(97*((2000000000123450*100)/97)))
```

---

**EDIT 1**

Try with below, it will return 46

```
Function DblMod(Dividend, Divisor)
    ' Declare two double precision variables
    Dim D1 As Double
    Dim D2 As Double
    Dim D3 As Double
    Dim str1
    Dim Str2
    ' Copy function arguments to local variables
    D1 = CDbl(Dividend)
    D2 = Divisor
    DblMod = CDec(D1) - (Round(CDec(D1) / D2) * D2)
End Function
```

---

```
Sub test()
    test = DblMod("3259300700853850", 97)
End Sub
```

Comment: Note that the last digit in the OP's 16 digit number has been changed

Answer (score 0):

Instead of dealing with very big numbers, just split them up like this:

```
Public Function ExtMod(Dividend As String, Divisor As Long) As Double
  Dim i As Long, j As Double
  For i = 1 To Len(Dividend)
    If Not IsNumeric(Mid(Dividend, i, 1)) Then
      j = j & Mid(Dividend, i)
      Exit For
    End If
    j = j * 10 + Mid(Dividend, i, 1)
    While j >= Divisor
      j = j - Divisor
    Wend
  Next
  ExtMod = j
End Function
```

Also works with decimals and locale should not matter. Only limitation is is the max length of strings which you probably never will hit.

Tested it with "123456789012345678901234567890.3241543" and 643 which is 435.3241543.

If you have any questions, just ask ;)