# Mod with Float Numbers gives wrong Result

Tags: vba, excel, modulo

When I try this Code:

```
A = 19 Mod 6.7
```

the Result is 5 but it should be 5.6
Can someone say me, whats going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Annoyingly, VBA will round the `6.7` to `7` as it doesn't have a *floating point modulus* function (cf. Java).

Effectively it evaluates `19 Mod CInt(6.7)`, and `CInt` uses German Rounding, rather than integer truncation.

If you want to duplicate the behaviour of the MOD function on a worksheet, see [VBA equivalent to Excel's mod function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4378047/vba-equivalent-to-excels-mod-function)

Answer (score 2):

MOD is an integer function in VBA. It would be better to use:

```
a - (b * (a / b))
```