# Linear Congruential Generator on VBA

Tags: vba, excel, random

i'm trying to replicate the Linear Congruential Generator in VBA but my procedure returns to me an Error '6': Overflow...

```
Sub test()
    Dim a As Long, c As Long, period As Long
    Dim seed As Long, sample As Long, max As Long
    Dim i  As Long

    seed = 1234
    sample = 2
    max = 100

    a = 48271
    c = 0
    period = 2 ^ 31 - 1

    For i = 1 To sample
        seed = (a * seed + c) Mod period
    Next i
End Sub
```

I think the problem is in the first expression of the for cycle, in detail

```
a*seed
```

in the second step of the cycle.
Any suggestion to solve the problem without splitting

```
a*seed
```

in

```
(100*seed+100*seed+100*seed+...+(a-100*n)*seed
```

Comment: @CallumDA I have tried declaring every number as Long but it still goes in overflow

Comment: the Debug function says 
seed = (a*seed+c) Mod period

Comment: I've updated your question so the code is minimal and instantly repeatable -- since I've updated the declarations and the problem persists I've also deleted my answer for now

Comment: Ok, thank you very much!

Comment: Does `Currency` overflow?

Comment: @MathieuGuindon, yeah. I swapped `seed =` for `Debug.Print` and it works just fine - the output is `59566414`. Well within the limits of a `Long`

Comment: @CallumDA so, you're posting an answer then? ;-)

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4378073/1188513

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [decimal subtype](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-msoffice_custom/decimal-data-type/2aed8b4c-a37f-4a33-a3df-d83b4004c543) of variant and write your own mod function for decimals:

```
Function DecMod(a As Variant, n As Variant) As Variant
    Dim q As Variant
    q = Int(CDec(a) / CDec(n))
    DecMod = a - n * q
End Function

Sub test()
    Dim a As Variant, c As Variant, period As Variant
    Dim seed As Variant, sample As Long, max As Long
    Dim i  As Long

    seed = CDec(1234)
    sample = 5
    max = 100

    a = CDec(48271)
    c = 0
    period = CDec(2 ^ 31 - 1)

    For i = 1 To sample
        Debug.Print seed
        seed = DecMod(seed * a + c, period)
    Next i
End Sub
```

Output:

```
1234 
59566414 
1997250508 
148423250 
533254358
```

Comment: Nice workaround (+1)... don't suppose you know the reason for the original overflow? I was really hoping for an explanation!

Comment: @CallumDA In the original code (using `Long`), the overflow occurs in the second pass through the loop when VBA tries to evaluate `1234*59566414` as a Long. If one of the operand overflows then the  entire calculation overflows even if the resulting `Mod` doesn't. It would be nice if the implementation of `Mod` was more robust.