# How do I use Excel's built-in modulo function (MOD) in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, modulo, excel-2016

My questions is somewhat related to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4378047/4581200).

However, let's say I want to use Excel's built-in `MOD` (modulo) function in VBA. 
[This site](https://spreadsheeto.com/vba-vlookup/) suggests that using `Application.WorksheetFunction.[insert name of Excel function]` would provide the desired effect.

However, `Application.WorksheetFunction.MOD` does not work.

In fact, when I simply type `Application.WorksheetFunction.` into VBA, a dropdown menu appears providing a list of function names to choose from, but `MOD` is not provided in this list!

2 questions:

1. What's going on here?
2. How do I actually use Excel's built-in `MOD` function in VBA?

---

*Note: I started down this path b/c I'm trying to get `1.7 Mod 0.5` to equal `0.2` using VBA's `Mod` function, but it produces `#VALUE!` in the resulting Excel cell I apply my VBA function to. However, if I type `MOD(1.7,0.5)` directly into Excel, I get the correct answer (i.e., `0.2`)*

Comment: `Mod` is a valid operator in `vba`. e.g. `123 Mod 11 = 2`

Comment: @UriGoren Then why does using `1.7 Mod 0.5` in VBA ***not*** work while typing `MOD(1.7,0.5)` directly into Excel *does*? (the answer should be 0.2)

Comment: As a quick reference answer to my last comment: as QHarr points out in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53660665/4581200) the reason `1.7 Mod 0.5` doesn't work is because VBA's `Mod` only works with integers. I'd have to use `Evaluate("Mod(1.7,0.5)")` to make this work in VBA.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You use as is since it is an operator (with integers). Use `evaluate` if you want to use doubles etc e.g.

E.g.

```
Debug.Print 2 Mod 12
Debug.Print Evaluate("Mod(1.7,0.5)")
Dim x As Double, y As Double
x = 1.7
y = 0.5
Debug.Print Evaluate("Mod(" & x & "," & y & ")")
```

See [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/mod-operator).  There are [limitations](https://excel.tips.net/T003302_Large_Numbers_in_the_MOD_Function.html) with large numbers. A common workaround, from Microsoft, is:

```
=number-(INT(number/divisor)*divisor)
```

Comment: @QHarr `2 Mod 12` works, but @theforestecologist is correct in that the original values, that is `1.7 Mod 0.5`, returns the error.  And no, I didn't down vote.

Comment: Because you must use evaluate. Mod in VBA required integers.

Comment: @QHarr could you update your answer demonstrating how to use `Evaluate` with variables? For example: if I set up `Function modFunc(x,y)` how could I incorporate changing values for `x` and `y` in `Debug.Print Evaluate("Mod(x,y)")`?

Comment: Thanks for the edits. Lastly: why do I need to include `Debug.Print`?

Comment: You don't. It was in case you were using test values for x and y

Comment: Ohhhhh. Got it. Thanks! +1 for your help, mate!